# Call a parent method after all the child __init__ are done like a "finally __init__" method

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, inheritance

I want to call a method from my parent class at the end of child class **init**. To do that i know i can just call a `super().parent_method()` at the end of each child class.
The probleme is that i'm starting to have a lot of function inheriting from my super class so i wondered if it was possible to have a sort of "finally **init**" declared in the super class that can be called after all the inheritance **init** are made ?
If not, is there a smart way to replicate it ?
It's not like it's a real problem but i'm just curious about making things faster :)

I tried to call at the end of each inheriting class the parent method which works perfectly fine i didn't find in the documentation method that would help me.

For example i want my `Formulaire` super tkinter class to show a busy state cursor at the end of the **init** and turn back the normal cursor after the long loading time of the children class `Formulaire_ticket`.

Here's an example of what i want to achieve with the parent method called after the child init:

```
from tkinter import *

class Formulaire(Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__(controller)
        self.set_busy_cursor(controller)
    
    def set_busy_cursor(self, controller):
        controller.config(cursor = "watch")

    def unset_busy_cursor(self, controller):
        controller.config(cursor = "")
        


class Formulaire_ticket(Formulaire):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__(controller)
        """
        Long data process that require a busy cusror
        """
        a = 1
        
        for i in range(100000):
            controller.update()
            a = a*2
        super().unset_busy_cursor(controller)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

btn = Button(root, text = "Busy", command = lambda: Formulaire_ticket(controller=root))
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Now if i want to do the same without calling the parent function at the end of the child class because i have hundreds of class inheriting from my parent class how can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any such thing as a "finally init", but you can simply turn the logic on its head to make that easy:

```
class Formulaire(Frame):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        super().__init__(controller)
        self.set_busy_cursor(controller)
        self.setup()
        self.unset_busy_cursor(controller);

    def setup(self):
        pass
    
    def set_busy_cursor(self, controller):
        controller.config(cursor = "watch")

    def unset_busy_cursor(self, controller):
        controller.config(cursor = "")
```

Now have your child classes implement their long running code in `setup` instead of `__init__`.

Comment: The problem is that it's just that i'm making a very big project and i have dozens of class that inherit from the super class. So if i put each inheriting class method in the super class it is just as much work as putting the super method at the end of each inheriting class. If there's not a way to reproduce a "finally init" i'll do the standard method :)

Comment: *"if i put each inheriting class method in the super class"* — I didn't say you should do that…!? I'm saying your child class overrides `setup` instead of `__init__` and puts its code into its own method called `setup`.

Comment: I didn't  understand that way, ok it can work thank you ! No need to be unpleasant tho.